# Only receiving one email from SMTP per account?

Tags: email, smtp

I've been playing around with SMTP, but I'm noticing an unfortunate pattern with the mail I send. I'm able to send an email once, and then when I send it again, it says it was successful, but I don't receive the email.

So I tried sending it to a different account. This account gets the email. I send another email. It's also "successful", but I don't get a second email on this account.

If I wait awhile, I can send another email to the account. But if I send the same message again a minute later, it won't show.

I think gmail is trying to protect me from "spam", but it makes testing very difficult. Is there a way I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it's probably Gmail that "protects" you. I would suggest using a different email for testing.

Depending on the nature of yourbtests, you could also try to view the email in the browser.